# List comprehension in python if/else

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Input

```
['27', ' 5', '6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '','','','','','34','32','','','','']
```

I want my output to be something like this. The logic is to replace 4 consecutive duplicate empty strings **' '** with single new item while retaining the rest of the items.

```
['27', ' 5', '6', ' 0', ' 0', 'LOL','LOL', '34','32','LOL']
```

I'm confused as to why this only gives the output as

```
['LOL','LOL','LOL']
```

My code is as below:

```
from itertools import groupby,repeat
L =   ['27', ' 5', '6', ' 0', ' 0', '', '', '', '','','','','','34','32','','','','']
grouped_L = [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(L)]

final_list = [z if x=='' else x   for x,y in grouped_L for z in repeat('LOL',(y//4))  ]
print(final_list)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output? Your code fails because `repeat(..., (y//4))` is going to result in *zero* repeats for any `y < 4`, so the left-hand expression is not executed at all (a loop over zero items produces no iterations).

Comment: Where did the `'34'` and `'32'` disappear to? And why doesn’t the consecutive `' 0', ' 0'` produce a `'LOL'`?

Comment: My bad man. I forgot to edit them. sorry!!

Comment: Is the repeat count of `4` actually relevant at all? Do you only want to replace multiples of `4`?

Comment: Yes it is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your innermost loop produces no results for any `y < 4`:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> y = 4
>>> list(repeat('LOL', y // 4))
['LOL']
>>> y = 3
>>> list(repeat('LOL', y // 4))
[]
```

With no iterations, nothing will be added to the resulting list.

You'll need to use a different strategy; you'll need to include `LOL` for groups with length `y` of 4 and up, and for everything else use the original, and *always* repeat:

```
[value
 for x, y in grouped_L 
 for value in repeat(x if y < 4 else 'LOL', y if y < 4 else y // 4)]
```

So the above either includes `x * y` for `y < 4`, otherwise it'll include `'LOL' * (y // 4)` for anything else:

```
>>> [value
...  for x, y in grouped_L
...  for value in repeat(x if y < 4 else 'LOL', y if y < 4 else y // 4)]
['27', ' 5', '6', ' 0', ' 0', 'LOL', '34', '32', 'LOL']
```

Comment: That is just what i needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Without list comprehensions but IMHO it is a much easier solution.

```
a = ['27', ' 5', '6', ' 0', ' 0', 'LOL', '34','32','LOL']

def remove_duplicates(w_duplicates):
    wo_duplicates = []
    for el in w_duplicates:
        if wo_duplicates and el == wo_duplicates[-1]:
            continue
        wo_duplicates.append(el)
    return wo_duplicates

print remove_duplicates(a)
```

Comment: Nice I found the solution without list comprehension too. But list comprehension is what i was looking for.